# Python 3.9: formationstring

Tags: python-3.x, string, variables, methods

im very new to programming and i have a question on a formatstring.

On Python 3.9 IDLE

```
breite = 8
spalte = str(breite)
formatstring = "{:>"+spalte+"} | {:>"+spalte+"}" #works!
```

my question is why cant i just write:

```
breite = "8"
formatstring = "{:>breite} | {:>breite}" #doesnt work!
```

what is the purpose of the plus signs in "+spalte+" ? and why do i have to put breite in another variable, spalte = str(breite) ? THANK YOU

Comment: Check out [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

Comment: thank you for the quick answer

Comment: After looking at your example more closely, I am not sure that is the issue.  It looks to me like formatstring is nothing more than the concatenation of a series of strings to include:  ```"{:>"````, ```spalte```,   ```"} | {:>"``` , and ```"}"```.  In this case, to concatenate the string spalte you must add it to the previous string using the + operator,

Comment: yes!!! that was the issue. after your tip i was about to watch a 30 min youtube video, but when i looked more closely it was just a series of strings! Anyways... thanks alot.